# how to tint a black and white .png image to a certain color in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a .png image that I need to tint a custom color with the RGB values of 207, 173, 23.  (https://github.com/pret/pokecrystal/blob/master/gfx/tilesets/players_room.png?raw=true)

I did some research and found the following code:

```
public BufferedImage getBufferedImage(String source, int redPercent, int greenPercent, int bluePercent) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;

    try{
        f = new File(source);
        img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            p = (a<<24) | (redPercent*r/100<<16) | (greenPercent*g/100<<8) | (bluePercent*b/100);

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
        }
    }

    return img;
}
```

This method is supposed to return a buffered image with the entered RGB values. However, whenever I use it, it only returns a lighter of darker version of the image with no color. I am wondering if the problem lies in the image itself, perhaps having to do with the transparency, or is the problem the code?

Comment: Just skimming through: there should be a `return null` or similar after `System.out.println(e)` rather than carrying on regardless after printing the error. (Not that that'll be the problem of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the PNG image is set up to hold greyscale data only and so the BufferedImage `img` is also only capable of holding greyscale data. To fix this just create an output BufferedImage in RGB colour mode.

I also tidied up your exception handling.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


class SOQuestion {
    public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(String source,
            int redPercent, int greenPercent, int bluePercent) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = new File(source);
            img = ImageIO.read(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }

        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

                int a = (p>>24) & 0xff;
                int r = (p>>16) & 0xff;
                int g = (p>>8) & 0xff;
                int b = p & 0xff;

                p = (a<<24) | (redPercent*r/100<<16) |
                    (greenPercent*g/100<<8) | (bluePercent*b/100);

                out.setRGB(x, y, p);
            }
        }

        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage result = SOQuestion.getBufferedImage(args[0], 81, 68, 9);
        File outputfile = new File("output.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(result, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each pixel is assigned a 32-bit binary code:
        A              R              G              B
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
              8             16             24             32
first 8 bits store the value of the alpha-value
second 8 bits store the red value
third 8 bits store the green value
fourth 8 bits store the blue value

The maximum possible value of an 8 bit binary is (000000000000000000000000)11111111 : 255 in decimal and 0xFF in hexacode

Comment: so we are isolating the argb values from this string of binary by shifting them to the end and masking all but the last 8 bits with & 0xff, then multiplying each rgb value by a percentage, then using | to put them back together - is my understanding of the code correct?